# error with slap.d while installing any new software

Tags: openldap

I am trying to install wireshark (this issue is not specific to wireshark) on my ubuntu box  and I keep getting the following error for slap.d:

```
Setting up slapd (2.4.23-6ubuntu6.1) ...
  Creating initial configuration... mkdir: cannot create directory `/etc/ldap/slapd.d': File exists
dpkg: error processing slapd (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 slapd
```

Besides uninstalling or trying to update open LDAP or slap.d, is there any other action that can be taken to resolve this issue?  I am trying the install as root user & I have tried moving the slap.d conf file so far but without any luck.  Any thoughts on troubleshooting/resolving this issue will be quite welcome.
thank in advance

Comment: I ended up re-installing ubuntu as I was not able to properly configure slap.d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up re-installing ubuntu.